# TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'project_id in flask application

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I have this route

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_restful import Api
from resources.Hello import Hello
from resources.Users import UserResource
from resources.Projects import ProjectResource
from resources.Actions import ActionResource

api_bp = Blueprint('api', __name__)
api = Api(api_bp)
# Get by id
api.add_resource(ProjectResource, '/projects/<int:project_id>', endpoint = 'get_by_id')
```

in my flask application and I am trying to pass the user `id` when I use the api endpoint `/projects/<project_id>` in my postman toll.

I have the function servicing that route in this form:

```
from flask import request
from flask_restful import Resource
from  Model import db, Project, ProjectSchema

projects_schema = ProjectSchema(many=True)
project_schema = ProjectSchema()

"""
Get project by id
"""
def get_by_id(project_id):
    project = Project.query.filter_by(id=project_id).first()
    project = projects_schema.dump(project).data
    return {'status': 'success', 'data': project}, 200
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'project_id
```

I have check the syntax for passing such a parameter and I seem to be doing it properly, but I might be wrong. Any pointers as to why my code throws this error would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if that causes the error. But is it intended that the endpoint points to the function? That looks a bit weird to me, maybe it's causing a name clash?!

Comment: I believe that is how it's supposed to be!